# Bad int8 external representation "6*725" in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I am getting an error like "Bad int8 external representation "6*725" " in netezza while executing a stored procedure . This stored procedure takes data from a table does some transformations and load into another table.

Can any one please help me .

Thanks,
Brajendra

Comment: The error sounds like you have a `string` of `'6*725'` in an `integer` column.  Try the following `cast(decode(columnx,'6*725','4350',columnx) as integer)`

Comment: yes you are rite . when I checked the data I got the issue .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

FYI: May be multiple answers to this question because do not have the query that you ran to get the error.

If you did a direct INSERT command like this, the order of the columns of the table from the select clause DO NOT match the order of the columns of the table from the insert clause.  Most database management systems doesn't care what the order is, but Netezza does.  The fact that it threw the "Bad int8" just means the first column it couldn't match in the select clause has that data type, and the data type in the insert clause has a different data type.

```
INSERT INTO DB1..TABLE1
SELECT * FROM DB1..TABLE2;
```

You can fix with one of two methods.  Either change the order of the columns by dropping and recreating the table.  Or use explicit column names in the INSERT INTO/SELECT command.